# jquery trim leading zeros from date of format 01/02/2010

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, trim

How do I trim javascript date object returned as 01/26/2012 into 1/26/2012? 
it could be applicable for both month or days.
So 01/01/2012 should be trimmed as 1/1/2012.
Regular expression? jquery trim function? I am not sure how to go on this?

```
var date=date.replace(/^0+/, '');
```

or

```
var trimmed = s.replace(/\b(0(?!\b))+/g, "")
```

Comment: urgh - most people want the reverse :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a simple string operation, a RegEx can be used:

```
date = date.replace(/\b0(?=\d)/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is indeed a date object [format it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript).

Quick example (See it [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/xsHuG/)):

```
var today = new Date();
var today_string = (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getDate() + '/' + today.getFullYear();
alert(today_string);
```

Either way, this is not a good use of regular expressions.

Comment: Why would you convert a string to a date object, if only a simple string operation is desired?

Comment: The OP states *How do I trim javascript **date object***. Furthermore, I wouldn't consider regular expressions a *simple string operation*.

Comment: I am sorry the date is just text not a date object

Comment: I maintain that converting to a Date Object would be worth. Especially if you're using the *date* elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a Date object first.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Javascript doesn't have built-in formatting functions for dates, but there are a lot of simple libraries that serve this need. Personal favorite: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format